# Compose selectors both way without circular dependency

Tags: angular, architecture, ngrx, circular-dependency

I want to combine two selectors to get products and get categories.

The categories have a reference to their products.

```
//category.selectors.ts
import {ProductSelector} from "./product.selector.ts"

export const selectCategoryEntitiesDeep = createSelector(
        CategorySelectors.selectCategoryEntities,
        ProductSelectors.selectProductEntitiesDeep,
        (categoryEntities, productEntities): Dictionary<Category> => {
            const _categoryEntities = ObjUtils.cloneDeep(categoryEntities);
            Object.keys(_categoryEntities).forEach(id => {
                _categoryEntities[id]["products"] = _categoryEntities[id].productsIds.map(productId => {
                    return productEntities[productId];
                });
            });

            return _categoryEntities;
        }
    );
```

That's straight forward.
When composing the selector for products I want to add a reference to all categories that the product belongs to. In order to be able to do that I need to import the category.selctor.ts into product.selector.ts.
As I am importing products into categories as well this will lead to a circular dependency.

```
// product.selectors.ts
import {CategorySelectors} from "./category.selectors.ts"

export const selectProductEntitiesDeep = createSelectorFactory<{}, Dictionary<Product>>(StateUtils.customObjectMemoizer)(
        ProductSelectors.selectEntities,
        CategorySelectors.selectCategoryEntities,
        (productEntities: Dictionary<Product>,
         categoryEntities: Dictionary<Category>
        ) => {
            return createProductDictionary(productEntities, categoryEntities)
        }
    );
```

What are the solutions to prevent this?
Right now I am using another more abstract file for combining selectors from different states. That doesn't seem like a scalable solution. It's a little messy.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Did you manage to solve the problem? If so, could you please share your solution?

Comment: You need to restructure your code. I created anotehr layer of selectors that depend on foreign selectors.

merged-one.selector.ts imports from
base-one.selector
base-two.selector

Just make sure that the base selectors don't depend on other selectors.

Comment: Thx. That helped me out!. You should provide that Solution as an Answer. I would give you an upvote ;) (See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Thank you. It's posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restructure your code. I created another layer of selectors that depend on foreign selectors. merged-one.selector.ts imports from base-one.selector and base-two.selector Just make sure that the base selectors don't depend on other selectors